# How do I assign another hard disk to root in linux?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

The following is the current status of my disk:

```
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop1                       7:1    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop2                       7:2    0 79.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22923
loop3                       7:3    0  103M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23541
loop4                       7:4    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
sda                         8:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0   28G  0 part 
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   28G  0 lvm  /
├─sda4                      8:4    0   30G  0 part 
└─sda5                      8:5    0 1007K  0 part 
sr0                        11:0    1  1.4G  0 rom
```

I added sda4 as above, is there any way to increase the root capacity to sda4?

Comment: I only see one hard disk in the system.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you want to combine/merge sda3 and sda4 to have a 58G root partition right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your question should be "How to resize root logical volume with another partition". Here is a [nice howto](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/resize-lvm-simple)

1. Create a backup of your important data!
2. Initialize physical volume for use by LVM:
   `$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda4`
3. Extend the Volume Group with your partition (I guess it is ubuntu--vg, but check it with `vgs` command) `$ sudo vgextend ubuntu--vg /dev/sda4`
4. Extend the Logical Volume(I guess it is ubuntu--lv, but check it with `lvs` command) `$ sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu--vg/ubuntu--lv`.
5. Resize your fs, using your fs tools or a graphical tool like Gparted